# como obtener datos de mysql con jquery en php mvc

Tags: php, jquery, mvc

soy novato en programacion y ando aprendiendo php mvc sin ningun framework, mis preguntas son, debo hacer las consultas en el modelo o en el controlador?, y que script debo cargar con jquery para obtener esos datos sin recargar la pagina?

Comment: Giovanny te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: muchas gracias la editare saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las consultas a Base de Datos se hacen en la capa MODELO. Si bien puedes implentar MVC desde cero, hay algunos frameworks que te pueden ayudar para usar MVC en php, como codeigniter, laravel, phalcon, etc. Framework MVC: https://www.genbetadev.com/frameworks/un-punado-de-frameworks-php-que-te-haran-la-vida-mas-simple

Para obtener los datos sin recargar la pagina usas AJAX, jQuery tienes distintas funciones ajax que te simplificaran y facilitaran el uso de ajax, como $.ajax, $.get, $.post, etc. Este link te puede dar mas referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Suerte.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu genial ayuda, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Las consultas a la Base de Datos se hacen en el Modelo,el controlador contiene el código necesario para responder a las acciones que se solicitan en la aplicación. Sin embargo eso lo podías encontrar en google, esta web es para ayudar a resolver los errores de código, por lo que te insto a que no hagas preguntas de ese estilo.La comunidad tiene muy buena disposición en ese sentido, siempre me han ayudado :D. Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias,